# Escape XML tags in textarea

Tags: java, xml, jsp, spring-boot, escaping

I am working on spring boot with jsp in which I have a requirement to show an XML string in a jsp textarea. I ran into a strange problem while displaying the XML. The first tag just got ripped off and an extra `">` added at the end

**Note.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**greetings.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>            
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/smartxml/openxml" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Open" name="btnOpen" /><br/><br/>
            <textarea name="txtXml" rows="45" cols="223" value="${fileContent}"></textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**IndexController.java**

```
    @Controller
    public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(params = "btnOpen", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
            try {
                InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(is, writer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                String fileContent = writer.toString();
                model.addAttribute("fileContent", xmlOperation.readXml(is));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            return "greeting";
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>">
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<textarea name="txtXml" rows="45" cols="223">${fileContent}</textarea>
```

Comment: When I apply try your update, the textarea becomes empty.

Comment: @NewBeeDeveloper Check Updates 2 )))